# How to make Object.assign work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, assign

### Background

I am trying to extend the functionality of an old object via `Object.assign`, by passing in a new object with an additional feature.

```js
    const oldObj = () => { 
        const printLog = () => console.log("hello");
        return {printLog};
    };
    
    const newObj = () => {   
        const test = () => {
            printLog(); //fails here!
            console.log("world");
        };
        return {test}; 
    };
    
    const mix = Object.assign(oldObj(), newObj());
    
    mix.printLog();
    mix.test();
```

### Problem

My `mix` object fails execution, even though it has bot `printLog` and `test` methods:

```
Object {printLog: function, test: function}
```

### Question

How can I fix my code so that the `test` function will work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access `printLog`, you have to access it through `this`. However, your function `test` cannot be an arrow function because arrow functions use the `this` context of the context they're defined in, so to get the result you want, change `printLog()` into `this.printLog()` and switch `test` from an arrow function to a regular function:

```js
const oldObj = () => { 
    const printLog = () => console.log("hello");
    return {printLog};
};

const newObj = () => {   
    const test = function() {
        this.printLog(); //fails here!
        console.log("world");
    };
    return {test}; 
};

const mix = Object.assign(oldObj(), newObj());

mix.printLog();
mix.test();
```

Comment: Good explanation. So, the arrow function will use the `this` context of `newObj` which doesn't have a `printLog` function. But how does the `function` have access to it? Can you explain?

Comment: Correct. The regular `function` has no `this` binding by default. When you invoke a method using the dot syntax (`object.method()`), the method is bound to the object, so when you call `mix.test()`, `test` is bound to `mix` (for that invocation). Because arrow functions are bound when they're created, their `this` value cannot be changed.

Comment: Perfect explanation! Can you add this ?

Answer (score 0):

edit: Change your code to this:

```
   const oldObj = () => { 
        const printLog = () => console.log("hello");
        return {printLog};
    };

    const newObj = () => {   
        function test() {
            this.printLog(); 
            console.log("world");
        };
        return {test}; 
    };

    const mix = Object.assign(oldObj(), newObj());


    mix.printLog();
    mix.test();
```

Comment: Oh i see.  Let me take another look.

Comment: Allow me to correct. The output I want is `hello\nworld`.

Comment: Check out @SimpleJ's explanation.

Comment: What did you change, and why?

Comment: I changed the printLog to access this.printLog.  The printLog function is a property on the object that 'this' refers to.